# Angular active ng-class isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have some angular code that is supposed to assign a class to only the parent element of the link clicked. This seems to work initially, but then after clicking around a bit, the code seems to get stuck. Here is some sample code of what I'm working with:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id" class="row" ng-class="{'active': selectItem.this == item.id}">
<a ng-click="selectItem.this = item.id">Move to top</a> {{item.name}}
```

```
$scope.selectItem = { this: -1 };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jhahff7OyVTVt615BBp3?p=preview

Any help would be great!

Comment: It worked fine for me, after some time to load. I think it's just being picky where you click. You can add the css to make "a { cursor: pointer; }" to make it more evident when you're hovering over it and when you're not.

Comment: this seems to be working correctly;  the problem is that only part of the text is an anchor.  clicking on `"Move to top"` works, clicking on the `"item #"` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the whole text a clickable DOM

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id" class="row" ng-class="{'active': selectItem.this == item.id}">
  <a ng-click="selectItem.this = item.id">Move to top <span ng-bind="item.name"></span></a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the **a** tag with **p** tag and bind an click event to the **p** tag. With this refactoring, I don't see any lagging or weird behaviour.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id" class="row" 
       ng-class="{'active': selectItem.this == item.id}">
       <p style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click=selectedItem()>
           Move to top {{item.name}}
       </p> 
  </div>
</body>
```

**In controller**

```
$scope.selectItem = {};
$scope.selectedItem = function () {
  $scope.selectItem.this = this.item.id;
};
```

Let me know if you still see any issues.